# Unable to Change Format When Using Parameters to Swap Fields in Tableau

Tags: tableau-api

I am Unable to Change Format(Incremental RR is in percentage(%) and rest are in numbers($)) When Using Parameters to Swap Fields. I have created one parameter named -Select metric and written calculation as below:

`IF [Select Metric]='Avg HH-Balance' then [Average Balance] 
ELSEIF  [Select Metric]='CPI-HH (Checking)' then [CPI-HH (Checking)] 
ELSEIF  [Select Metric]='CPI-A (Any Acct)' then [CPI-A (Any Acct)] 
ELSEIF  [Select Metric]='Incremental RR' then [Incremental Response Rate] else null
END`

The format it's taking is Automatic but I want the axis to change according to the selection of parameters.Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out this [great answer](https://learningtableaublog.wordpress.com/2016/07/09/dynamic-axes-and-number-formatting/) from Andy Kriebel.

Comment: I want to show Legends for these 4 metrics in the dashboard but unable to do so for all cos of this hidden sheets mentioned in the examples. How can I achieve that.Thanks.

Comment: Since you marked this question as correct and your new comment asks a new question, can you please ask that as a brand new question instead of in the comments?